Parallel Send to WebSocket using ClientWebSocket
Regarding ClientWebSocket Microsoft documentation states that

Exactly one send and one receive is supported on each ClientWebSocket
object in parallel. Issuing multiple sends or multiple receives at the
same time (for example, without awaiting, or from multiple threads
without synchronization) is not supported and will result in an
undefined behavior. Ensure that the previous operation is awaited (or
completed) before issuing the next one. You should serialize the
access via whatever mechanism works best for you, for example, by
using a lock or a semaphore.

I have a scenario where there is a unique Id in each message sent and the unique Id is present in the response as well. I am storing all the receive messages and using the unique Id to match the response against the sent message.
In this case can I issue multiple sends?
What kind of the undefined behavior is Microsoft pointing?

Buffer corruption, presumably.

Does it matter? If you want a correctly working program you need to follow the rules, whatever they may be.
